# Multi node cluster setup with home network for parallelized computing using e.g. hadoop, MPI or Rmpi

Tags: macos, terminal, network

currently I am reading more and more about multi-core processing (threading) and parallel computing. So I was curious about how to use my 4-core processor to calculate parallelized algorithms using Thread-Libraries etc..

My home network consists of an iMac (i7-4cores) and a Macbook (late 2008-2cores). I was googling around to find out how to set up a home server from my iMac to create multiple nodes from my iMac and Macbook to be able to compute my algorithms parallelized on both machines. I also heard of a local version of hadoop to manage parallelized computations on network nodes.

Therefore I am very interested in a workflow or in some help to set up :

1. A WLAN network with multiple nodes from my iMac or Macbook without using the "OSX Server App" (just from the Terminal or other open sources) to be able to compute jobs simultaneously on my iMac and Macbook using my home WLAN network.
2. Setting up hadoop on both machines and starting a simple example for
   a map reduce job (so I can "see" that the job has been distributed to my iMac and Macbook).
3. Some tips and tricks to manage multiple nodes and distributed processes in a home network.

Thank's a lot!